# Chocolate printing

Tags: food, chocolate

I have seen lots of printers that print chocolate using a syringe with molten chocolate. But, even cooler, would it be possible to print chocolate using some kind of feed system for **continuous** chocolate printing, so large objects and for a prolonged time, not only lasting the content of one syringe with molten chocolate ?

Things to consider are IMO:

- How to keep the chocolate long enough in a molten, viscous state
  enough to print ?
- Chocolate needs a tempering temperature, which
  means it needs to be around 32-37 degrees celsius, else it doesn't
  shine but gets a dull look (or turns white after a while).
- Chocolate
  is food, so you need foodsave equipment in the whole chain that is in
  contact with the chocolate.

Maybe a peristaltic pump that keeps pumping the molten chocolate to the extruder, which might be a valve that can be open/closed from G-code ?

Comment: For some cases you are better of printing a two part negative (mold) from food safe PLA and pouring molten chocolate from a hole you designed in your editor. I think there are scripts/tools for generating molds. They are usually used for making candle or soap molds and such but could be adopted for choloclate. That mold will not be too reusable as tiny pieces can get trapped between the layers and rot. But you could use it to make a batch of cholocate figures in a day or so.  On the contrary, if your print takes 10+ hours a syringe printed might not work because it might spoil during printing.

Comment: continued: the walls of the mold might need to be covered with some food  safe material to prevent the choloclate sticking to it

Comment: Hello @Dimitri Modderman, I noticed your question has been up for a while now. Have any of the answers below been able to solve your question? If so, would you mind accepting the appropriate answer. If not, what is missing so that we may help you further? Also, if you have figured it out on your own, you can always answer and accept your own solution. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a recommendation question.

Answer (score 11):

Update: I found a nice article about chocolate printing: https://all3dp.com/2/chocolate-3d-printer-all-you-need-to-know/

---

You are searching for chocolate extruder. I did not find one, which would fulfill all your requirements. You have to adapt each solution.

### Zmorph3d Liquid paste extruder

- https://zmorph3d.com/cake-and-chocolate-extruder/

According video on the page you insert chocolate in liquid form. That could be solved with heated chocolate container.

### Syringe based extruders

- http://www.open-electronics.org/3drag-is-now-printing-with-chocolate/
- http://richrap.blogspot.de/2012/04/universal-paste-extruder-ceramic-food.html
- http://www.instructables.com/id/Chocolate-Extruder-for-Ultimaker/

You can use a [2 liters syringe](http://esyringe.com/2l-jumbo-syringe.aspx). And if this is not enough then you can refill during print.

### Convert pellet extruder

Printing from chocolate pellets is simpler then printing from plastic pellets. Therefore if you use foodsave parts to build such a extruder then this is useable for you.

- https://www.youmagine.com/designs/universal-pellet-extruder-reprap-3d-printing

### Cooling

- [3DRAG CHOCO (Chocolate 3d printer) Cooling system explained](http://www.open-electronics.org/the-3drag-choco-chocolate-3d-printer-cooling-system-explained/)

### Shop

by Open-Electronics

- [Extrude for chocolate](https://store.open-electronics.org/index.php?_route_=3DCHOCO)
- [Syringe Heater for 3Drag chocolate printer](http://www.open-electronics.org/syringe-heater-for-3drag-chocolate-printer/)

Comment: Great answer. One comment I would make this a bit less Link dependent. So that when in the future and a large portion of these links no longer work, the answer still works.  IE posting the names along with the links.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into what Hershey did for this chocolate printer in junction with 3ds. Behold state of the art Chocolate 3d printing.. The
[CocoJett](http://richport3d.com/2015/02/17/3d-systems-unveils-the-cocojettm/)

That said there is little said about their tank system.

Far as the actual question it self. There is nothing to facilitate a large pool of continuous chocolate. It would be easy enough to build something that stirred the chocolate and a pump that feeds it in. At that point we are talking about a fair amount of new engineering. One could figure out how to map the E extrusion to a pump that would refill what was spent.

This section is just a bit of speculation.. 
I wonder. It seems to me that the way to go for XL coco printing would be powder. Bind it with an edible adhesive (hot sugar water maybe?). Have the printer refrigerated. Or just have a simple system that can change out the syringes of coco. Last you could just pause it while you change syringes.